# Using multidimensional array in a dictionary

Tags: arrays

In this program we translate English to German and use multidimensional array.But i have some problems.First we use words array to store words.In the first while loop we compare words[i][0] to " "(empty/space).since i=0 then words[0][0] means first string first word which is "dog".It is not empty, then how can compare dog and " " would be 1(true) to enter the loop.After that if English array's word wouldn't match with words array word, then stop(break).Get out the if loop.Then we add 1 with i.And the while loop run again.If no word match with English array's word, then it display" Not in Dictionary ".But how we enter the second if loop because "if(!strcmp(words[i][0], ""))".I mean , i don't
understand the code.Please anyone tell me it is the ran process of this program ,which i told.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char words[][2][40] = {

"dog","Hund",
"no","nein",
"year","Jahr",
"child","Kind",
"I","Ich",
"drive","fahren",
"house","Haus",
"to","zu",
"",""

};

int main(void)
{
    char english[80];
    int i;

    printf("Enter English word: ");
    gets(english);

    i=0;
    while(strcmp(words[i][0], "")){
        if(!strcmp(english, words[i][0])){
            printf("German translation: %s", words[i][1]);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if(!strcmp(words[i][0], ""))
        printf("Not in Dictionary\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to loop the full `length` of the array. Break if you find the value. And you should use a flag to know if you have found it or not (before you break, set a the flag to 1

Comment: Just notice. Currently, everything should work because you have "", "" at the end of the array. (don't remember C arrays, but is it correctly declared ? )